# Signalr windows desktop app on windows server 2012

Tags: winforms, signalr, windows-server-2012

I got Windows Desktop app with SignalR, need to put them on Windows Server 2012. I got problem when Client app (also using SignalR) need to connect to server part on Windows Server 2012, client cannot establish connection.

When I see on Windows Server 2012, after run SignalR app on WS2012, it listen on port of my app but cannot access to server via client app.

Also all this work normal when I run server on local network with lots of different clients on other computers.

The URL on WS2012 server app SignalR is http://123.44.44.45:8081
and on clients http://123.44.44.45:8081/signalr

(maybe I need to set some config on WS2012 that client can access to Server side app SignalR on WS2012)

Comment: did you enable Cors?

Comment: Can you enable tracing and provide us with more information as to what is going wrong? This link might help with performing this. http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/enabling-signalr-tracing